# Rendering content inside an Umbraco page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

I have a doc type that allows users to pick alerts for pages using a multi node treepicker. Alerts are instances of another document type.  Alerts don't have their own page so I wanted to use their selected template like a partial. What I want to do is something like:

```
var alertIds = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("alert");

List<umbraco.NodeFactory.Node> alerts = new List<umbraco.NodeFactory.Node>();

foreach (var alertId in alertIds.ToString().Split(','))
{
    alerts.Add(new umbraco.NodeFactory.Node(int.Parse(alertId)));
}
```

Then as an example I could do:

```
library.RenderTemplate(alerts[0].Id)
```

I wanted to do it this way because I like the idea that the templates can be chosen in `Umbraco` and just know how to render themselves, rather than creating a partial in my MVC project and handling it on that side. However, I run into the following error:

> "Error rendering template with id 1128:
>   'System.InvalidOperationException: A single instance of controller
>   'Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController' cannot be used to handle
>   multiple requests. If a custom controller factory is in use, make sure
>   that it creates a new instance of the controller for each request.\r\n
>   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.VerifyExecuteCalledOnce()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext)\r\n   at
>   Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoMvcHandler.ExecuteUmbracoRequest()\r\n   at
>   Umbraco.Web.Templates.TemplateRenderer.RenderUmbracoRequestToString(RequestContext
>   requestContext)\r\n   at
>   Umbraco.Web.Templates.TemplateRenderer.ExecuteTemplateRendering(TextWriter
>   sw, PublishedContentRequest contentRequest)\r\n   at
>   Umbraco.Web.Templates.TemplateRenderer.Render(StringWriter writer)\r\n
>   at umbraco.library.RenderTemplate(Int32 PageId, Int32 TemplateId)'
>   "

Thanks in advance for checking this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you're trying but that's not the way to do it.

> Alerts don't have their own page so I wanted to use their selected template like a partial.

If a document type (node) is not a page but just a container for data you should leave it without the template. It is because umbraco will generate a url for that node and you will mess up your SEO.

> I wanted to do it this way because I like the idea that the templates can be chosen in Umbraco

You can create a dropdown property on your document type (new data type that will list all possible templates) to mimic the template selector. And when showing the node you would write something like:

```
switch(alert.GetPropertyValue<string>("template"))
{
    case "News": RenderForNews(alert);
    case "Frontpage": RenderForFrontpage(alert);
    ...
}
```